# why HTML Codes and css are not working on browser?

Tags: html, css, browser, wamp

I am creating a simple website using `vscode` and `wamp` but the problem is that when I change any html nothing happens. actually I have two input tags and `divs` but they don't appear.
I disabled the cache from chrome dev tools and meta tags but nothing happens and I tried `xampp` but nothing happens again.

any help ?

**HTML::**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Admin</title>
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
        <link href="index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="register_ajax.js" type="text/javascript"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box">
            Username:
            <input type="text" name="username"/>
            Password:
            <input type="text" name="password"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS::**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(186, 196, 38);
}

.box {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(75, 35, 35);
}

input {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

**UPDATE::**

when I change `css` background color of body for testing the color never changes although I disabled cache in dev tools. however when I open dev tools while refreshing the color changes but the html is still invisible as if I didn't write any html

[image]

Comment: How are you serving the website? Is it being served from a build output directory or the src directory?

Comment: @Dai www dir of wamp

Comment: I recommend ditching WAMP. Unless you’re doing something tightly integrated into Apache you’ll be fine with IIS Express that’s built-in to Visual Studio and without the headaches.

Comment: @Dai i don't know what you mean . explain to me please . check update

Comment: Don’t use WAMP.

Comment: @Dai and the alternative for development ! ? if IIS how to use it ?

Comment: @Dai --- Can you support that claim ... I find it rather nonsense, but correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ahmednader - Can you see if the CSS you serve on that page is indeed updated.

Comment: @Daniel check update pics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A script tag **MUST** be written as an opening **and** a closing tag. This means, instead `<script src="register_ajax.js" type="text/javascript"/>` write `<script src="register_ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`. After correcting that mistake everything worked fine on my computer.

Comment: wow. it worked but whenever I want to see an update I must keep the dev tools open is that wierd ? !!

Comment: Is there a way to make it refresh without the dev tools being opened ? and thanks for the answer